# Nested grep with SSH

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a following Shell command which runs successfully:

```
sed -e "1,/^$(date -d -24hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')/d" logfile | grep -A20 -B10 'Exception' | mail -s "Sample report" xyz@yourdomain
```

However, I have to SSH to a particular machine to run this. To avoid this, I modified it in following way which leads to the failure:

```
ssh myserver 'sed -e "1,/^$(date -d -24hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')/d" logfile | grep -A20 -B10 'Exception' | mail -s "Sample report" xyz@yourdomain '
```

What is wrong with this command? How can I fix this?

Comment: BTW, in the future, as opposed to simply "leads to failure", specify the details of that failure in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed your code in a quoted heredoc to avoid needing to modify it (which is an error-prone process by nature):

```
ssh myserver 'bash -s' <<'EOF'
  sed -e "1,/^$(date -d -24hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')/d" logfile \
    | grep -A20 -B10 'Exception' \
    | mail -s "Sample report" xyz@yourdomain
EOF
```

---

In the specific case here, the obvious reason that your original modifications failed was internal single quotes terminating the ones surrounding the code as a whole.

Specifically:

```
+'%Y-%m-%d %H'
```

...the first `'` in that expression terminates the one opening before the command, so the space isn't syntactically protected.

You could instead do the following, since your shell is bash:

```
ssh myserver $'sed -e "1,/^$(date -d -24hour +\'%Y-%m-%d %H\')/d" logfile | grep -A20 -B10 Exception | mail -s "Sample report" xyz@yourdomain'
```

`$''` is an extension within which backslashes can escape single quotes (and also be used for other literals -- `\n` for a newline, `\t` for a tab, etc), functionality not available with typical POSIX sh syntax.

By contrast, in POSIX sh, one can switch quoting types to embed a literal single-quote: `'foo'"'"'bar'` to defines a string with both `foo` and `bar` single-quoted, and separated by a single literal single-quote between them -- perfectly valid syntax, but not necessarily easy for readers unfamiliar with the idiom to process).

Comment: BTW, the point of `bash -s` is to allow you an easy way to pass arguments out-of-band from the code block -- so if you wanted your code block passed in the heredoc to refer to `"$1"` for the email address and `"$2"` for the subject, you could use `printf -v args_str '%q ' "$email" "$subject"` to escape them from interpretation by the enclosing shell, and then `ssh myserver "bash -s $args_str"`.